# Counting logins per day with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two tables.

1. Table `users` with the fields `id`, `name`, `email`, `login`, `pw`
2. Table `logins` with the fields `id`, `userid`, `status`, `day`

Now I want to create a table which I can order by the ammount of days each user has logged in.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, l.userid,
COUNT(DISTINCT l.day) AS daysall
FROM users u
JOIN logins l ON l.userid = u.id
ORDER BY u.name
```

But I don't get a list. Can anyone help me finding a solution?

Comment: What *do* you get, if not a list?

Comment: You are missing the group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user id to **GROUP BY** the user for count. Try this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, l.userid,
COUNT(DISTINCT l.day) AS daysall
FROM users u
JOIN logins l ON l.userid = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to group by user id,

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, l.userid,
COUNT(DISTINCT l.day) AS daysall
FROM users u
INNER JOIN logins l ON l.userid = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.name
```